# Loop nested animate function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to convert this code:

```
$('.spawn_worm').animate({
    left: '+=20px',
    top: '-=20px'
},100, "linear", function(){
    $('.spawn_worm').animate({
        left: '+=20px',
        top: '-=16px'
    },100, "linear", function(){
        $('.spawn_worm').animate({
            left: '+=20px',
            top: '-=12px'
        },100, "linear", function(){
            $('.spawn_worm').animate({
                left: '+=20px',
                top: '-=8px'
            },100, "linear", function(){
                $('.spawn_worm').animate({
                    left: '+=20px',
                    top: '-=4px'
                },100, "linear", function(){
                    $('.spawn_worm').animate({
                        left: '+=20px',
                        top: '+=0px'
                    },100, "linear", function(){
                        $('.spawn_worm').animate({
                            left: '+=20px',
                            top: '+=4px'
                        },100, "linear", function(){
                            $('.spawn_worm').animate({
                                left: '+=20px',
                                top: '+=8px'
                            },100, "linear", function(){
                                $('.spawn_worm').animate({
                                    left: '+=20px',
                                    top: '+=8px'
                                },100, "linear", function(){
                                    $('.spawn_worm').animate({
                                        left: '+=20px',
                                        top: '+=12px'
                                    },100, "linear", function(){
                                        $('.spawn_worm').animate({
                                            left: '+=20px',
                                            top: '+=16px'
                                        },100, "linear", function(){

                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

To something less stupid. Because it's gonna take me like 1 year to finish that and because it's a lot of code I think it can be solved with a loop.

I want the animate function property `left` to be always the same `+=20px`. And the property `top` to start in `-20px` and increase to `180px`, then decrease again to `180px` and finish after `(window.width)/20` loops.

Is this even posible?
Thank you and sorry for the noob question (:

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this. Change the if condition as per your need.

```
var count = parseInt(window.innerWidth/20);
function animateElement(){
    if(count){
        $('.spawn_worm').animate({
            left: '+=20px',
            top: '-=20px'
        }, 100, animateElement);
        count--;
    }
}
animateElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a looping like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var top = 20,
      sign = -1;

    anim();

    function anim() {
      $('.spawn_worm').animate({
        left: '+=20px',
        top: (sign == 1 ? '+' : '-') + '=' + top + 'px'
      }, 100, "linear", function() {
        if (sign * top < 16) {
          top += 2 * sign;
          if (!top) {
            sign = 1;
          }
          anim();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
.ct {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}
.spawn_worm {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
<div class="ct">
  <div class="spawn_worm"></div>
</div>
```